# need help in algorithm java

Tags: java, algorithm

i just started with algorithm with codes below

```
public class Dijkstra {
private static Heap h = new Heap();
private static int[][] g;
int n =6;
public Dijkstra() {
    g = new int[10][10];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the weight of each edges (for mobius use 9999)");

    for(int a=1;a<=n;a++)
    {
        for(int b=1;b<=n;b++)
        {
            if((a!=b)&&(a<b))
            {
                System.out.print(a+" and "+b+": ");
                g[b][a] = g[a][b] =sc.nextInt() ;

                if(g[a][b] == 0 )
                {
                    g[b][a] = g[a][b] = 9999;
                }
            }
        if(a==b)
            g[a][b]=9999;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Dijkstra dij = new Dijkstra();
    System.out.println(dij.solve(6, 6, 5));
}

public int solve(int numOfNodes, int source, int dest) 
{
    h.push(source, 0);

    while (!h.isEmpty()) 
    {
        int c = h.pop();

        if (c == dest)
            return h.cost[dest];

        for (int a = 0; a < numOfNodes; a++) 
        {
            if (g[c][a] > 0)
                h.push(a, h.cost[c] + g[c][a]);
        }
    }
    return -1;
    }
}

class Heap {
private int[] data;
private int[] index;
public int[] cost;
private int size;
Dijkstra ki = new Dijkstra();

public Heap() 
{
    data = new int[6];
    index = new int[6];
    cost = new int[6];

    for (int a = 0; a < ki.n; a++) 
    {
        index[a] = -1;
        cost[a] = -1;
    }

    size = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() 
{
    return (size == 0);
}

private void Up(int a) 
{
    int b;

    while (a > 0) 
    {
        b = (a - 1) / 2;

        if (cost[data[a]] < cost[data[b]]) 
        {
            // swap here
            int temp = index[data[a]];
            index[data[a]] = index[data[b]];
            index[data[b]] = temp;
            // swap here
            temp = data[a];
            data[a] = data[b];
            data[b] = temp;
            a = b;
        } 
        else
            break;
    }
    }

private void Down(int a) 
{
    int b, d;

    while (2 * a + 1 < size) 
    {
        b = 2 * a + 1;
        d = b + 1;

        if (d < size && cost[data[d]] < cost[data[b]]
                && cost[data[d]] < cost[data[a]]) 
        {

            int temp = index[data[d]];
            index[data[d]] = index[data[a]];
            index[data[a]] = temp;

            temp = data[d];
            data[d] = data[a];
            data[a] = temp;

            a = d;
        } 
        else if (cost[data[b]] < cost[data[a]]) 
        {

            int temp = index[data[b]];
            index[data[b]] = index[data[a]];
            index[data[a]] = temp;

            temp = data[b];
            data[b] = data[a];
            data[a] = temp;

            a = b;
        } 
        else
            break;
    }
}

public int pop() 
{
    int i = data[0];
    data[0] = data[size - 1];
    index[data[0]] = 0;
    size--;
    Down(0);
    return i;
}

public void push(int e, int f) 
{
    if (index[e] == 0) 
    {
        cost[e] = f;
        data[size] = e;
        index[e] = size;
        size++;
        Up(index[e]);
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (f < cost[e]) 
        {
            cost[e] = f;
            Up(index[e]);
            Down(index[e]);
        }
        }
     }
 }
```

i have this error but i dont know where i must fix it

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at algo.Heap.push(Dijkstra.java:176)
at algo.Dijkstra.solve(Dijkstra.java:52)
at algo.Dijkstra.main(Dijkstra.java:47)
Java Result: 1
```

output will be the shortest total weight between the root and the target
i suppose to input the weight of its node use dijkstra algorithm
can someone help me please

Comment: You are trying to access an Array of indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5. You are accessing the index of 6, which throws that exception.

Comment: In the file Dijkstra.java in line 176 you access an array at a place which is out of bound. For example your array has size 5 but you read/write at place 6.

Comment: how to add the array into "n" element

Comment: Is `data[size] = e;` on line 176? If not, which is line 176?

Comment: line 176 is if (index[e] == 0)

Answer (score 0):

you have only allowed for a total of 6 elements in your arrays but are trying to set a value at the 6th index. since the index starts at zero you are trying to set the 7th element which is out of bounds.

[see this tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: i need make the total become "n" element

Comment: Use an ArrayList, then you dont have to worry about the fixed number of elements since you can just .add as many elements as you like

Comment: @waterling can you give me an example

Comment: here's a tutorial on arraylists with example code http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Answer (score 0):

There arrays:

```
data = new int[6];
index = new int[6];
cost = new int[6];
```

have 6 elements, so when you use them, for example here:

```
cost[e] = f;
data[size] = e;
index[e] = size;
```

you should be sure that "e" and "size" are always < 6.

Check what is happening at row 176.

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

This Exception occurs when the index you have given is not there in the array.

> **ie :** If you have an array with 6 elements and you are looking for an
>   element in the 7th position It makes an
>   `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**I am not answering here because, it can be solved easily.**

Look here for more details [**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Heap` class arrays all have fixed size of 6 (which is wrong, it doesn't make sense to have such a limit there).

As soon as your algorithm starts, you invoke:

```
dij.solve(6, 6, 5)   // line 47
```

Which in turn calls

```
h.push(6, 0);        // line 52
```

and finally tries to get the element past the length of `index`:

```
if (index[6] == 0)   // line 176
```

Since `index` array has 6 elements and Java arrays are 0-based, this will throw the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You need a valid Java implementation of a [Fibonacci Heap](http://www.keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=fibonacci-heap).